# Running ANTLR grun (TestRig) on grammar in a package.

Tags: antlr, antlr4, grun

I have all the generated java files in a single directory after ANTLR execution, so I used some options to generate a separate directory and namespace to be stored and compiled to store all the generated files.

This is the grammar file:

grammar Expr;

```
prog: (expr NEWLINE)* ;
expr: expr ('*'|'/') expr
    | expr ('+'|'-') expr
    | INT
    | '(' expr ')'
    ;
NEWLINE : [\r\n]+ ;
INT     : [0-9]+ ;
```

I could get the generated files in a different directory with `o`, and add package information with `package` option.

```
java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar -listener -visitor -package expr -lib . -o gen/expr Expr.g4
```

Compiling the code requires `d` and `sourcepath` option in `javac`.

```
javac -cp .:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar -d out -sourcepath gen gen/expr/Expr*.java
```

I could check the code works from making the executable.

```
import expr.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class ExprRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create a CharStream that reads from standard input

        String filePath = "input.txt";
        File fileInput = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileInput);


        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(fileInputStream); 
        ExprLexer lexer = new ExprLexer(input); 
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer); 
        ExprParser parser = new ExprParser(tokens);
        ParseTree tree = parser.prog(); // begin parsing at init rule
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser)); // print LISP-style tree        
    }
}
```

I could build and run it.

```
javac -cp .:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar:out -d out -sourcepath . ExprRunner.java
java -cp .:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar:out ExprRunner
```

This is the directory structure.

[image]
After checking everything works fine, I tried to use grun (TestRig). I tried `grun Expr prog -tree` and `grun out/expr/Expr prog -tree`, but they did not work.

How to run `grun` on the ANTLR files located in other directories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, `grun` only works when all files are in the same folder. It is meant as a quick debugging tool.

### EDIT

For those who read this more recently: it seems things might have changed and this is now possible. Read raffian's answer to try the `-package` parameter (I did not try it myself).

Comment: Not entirely accurate - `grun` accepts qualified grammar option consistent with `-package` option used for generating the parser. See my answer above.

Comment: When writing the answer in 2016, there was no such option AFAIK. I also cannot find a reference to a `-package` param in the [TestRig](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/gui/TestRig.java) (which is what `grun` uses behind the scenes)

Comment: My comment was poorly worded, apologies, what I meant was `-package` is an option in `org.antlr.v4.Tool`, and if used, the classes generated should be accessed using the qualified grammar package name, in this case, `expr.Expr`

Comment: No worries. Ah, right, so the params passed to grun (not directly used by TestRig) are passed along to the org.antlr.v4.Tool class. I could remember at the time I did try a couple of things, but back then it did not work. Likely the current `grun` (which is now a Python script) behaves differently compared to the old one.

Answer (score 0):

What I do on Linux is to **change directory** (`cd`) before running `grun`.

My project directory has the following structure:

- Root folder/

  - src/ (where `.java` files are stored)
  - bin/ (where `.class` files are stored)
  - input/ (where input programs in `.txt` are stored)
  - Makefile

And my `Makefile` has the following rule:

```
start:
    @cd bin && cat ../$(INPUT) | grun MyGrammar program -gui
```

So when I call `make start INPUT="input/test.txt"` it starts `grun`, showing the parse tree for my input program.

Answer (score 0):

If you generated your parser with the following options:

```
-package expr -lib . -o gen/expr Expr.g4
```

..your parser classes now reside in Java package `expr`.
Now, when using `grun`, just qualify the grammar option so the tool can find the parser class based on its package name:

```
grun expr.Expr prog -tree
```

I confirmed this works with ANTLR 4.12.0, the only difference in my setup was packaging all generated parser/lexer classes in a maven library configured on my classpath.